# Deleting checked row(s) from a table in Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, datatable, primeng

I have this table

```
<p-dataTable [value]="example">
    <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
    <p-column field="a" header="column 1"></p-column>
    <p-column field="b" header="column 2"></p-column>
    <p-column field="c" header="column 3"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

And I now want to make a delete button that should delete the checked rows from the table.

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Delete" (click)="onclick()"></button>
```

How would I then proceed, I know I have to make a function in `component.ts` for

```
onclick()
```

Also my table is being created as

```
example = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.example.push({
        a: 'e1',
        b: 'e2',
        c: 'e3'
    });
};
```

But what to do in it to delete the checked rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly change the structure of **example** array and lets prepare a **selection array**:

```
example = [
    {field: 'a', header: 'e1'},
    {field: 'b', header: 'e2'},
    {field: 'c', header: 'e3'},
];

selectedItems = [];
```

Then generate the table and columns like this **(DRY)**:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="example" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedItems">
    <p-column *ngFor="let item of example" [field]="item.field" [header]="item.header"></p-column>        
</p-dataTable>

<button (click)="deleteSelected()">Delete the bastards!</button>
```

Then let's make them disappear:

```
deleteSelected(){
    selectedItems.forEach(function(item) {
        const index = example.indexOf(item);

        example.splice(index, 1);
    });
}
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but can it be done without making the selection array like you did cause in my code i am making the array with the .push thing cause i want multiple rows and dont wanna keep creating new arrays just to create more rows.

Comment: Can I ask where are you getting the array items from? If you know the starting items **(e1, e2, e3)** you should make them as I did right in the definition of the **example** array. And then you can add to that array when ever you want with **push**. You absolutely need the **selection array** because you need to keep track of which ones you want to delete.

Comment: to create the table in not using ngfor (in the html part), im just using pcolumn multiple times. So how would i then get the total index/size of array ? Another problem i am having is property example does not exist on type void which idk what it means. Still thanks for help.

Comment: Np, glad I could help you out. Ok thats a lot of questions, and I would need to build the actual table in oreder to help you. But, and please dont be ofended, from your questions I get the feeling you are kinda new to typescript/angular. I would strongly advise avoiding primeng at this stage and would focus on learning vanila Angular4 via courses. You will get a lot of bad habits othewise.

Comment: hey i fixed it, just used normal for loops and yes im very new to angular and typescript (couple of days).

Comment: Glad to hear  you did it. Good luck!